# シェルスクリプトで特定の文字列から特定の文字までを抽出したい

Tags: linux, shellscript

以下のようなログファイルがあります。

```
aaa 1234.234;
bbbb 5678.345;
ccc 12345.356;

aaa 2345.344;
bbbb 6789.354;
ccc 23456.678;
```

このファイルからbbbbの数値、"bbbb "から";"の間のみを抜き出したいです。
なお、bbbのような文字列はありません。
この数値の桁数は不定で、a-cのようなデータ組がいくつあるかも不定ですが、
可能なら別々の変数に、もしくは一つの変数に改行を含めて格納できないでしょうか。

補足です

```
ans=`grep -o `bbbb[^;]*` test.txt`
```

でbbbbから;まで抜け出せました。
更にsedでbbbb を置き換え、

```
ans=`echo "$ans"|sed -e 's/^bbbb //'`
```

で改行を含む抽出ができました。
これを行ごとに別の変数に格納したいのですが、
やはり行数が分からないと別々は難しいのでしょうか。

補足2
IFSに改行を指定することでうまくいきました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 1列目(アルファベット)が`aaa`, `ccc`は3文字で、`bbbb`だけ4文字ですが、抜き出すのは`bbbb`の場合だけで大丈夫ですか？(`bbb`とかは出てこない？)また、同じファイルの中に1列目が`bbbb`のまま、数字が異なる列が何度も出てくるイメージでしょうか。いくつ出現するのかあらかじめ分かっていないと、別々の変数に入れるのは難しいかなと思いました。

Comment: bbbbのみです。変数ひとつならgrepで抽出してsedでbbbb を消そうかと思っています

Comment: この様な事でしょうか？ `awk -F'[ ;]' '$1=="bbbb"{print $2}' test.txt`

Comment: ありがとうございます。awkコマンドでほしい数値を取り出せました。これを別々の変数に格納するのは難しいでしょうか。

Comment: 現実的な対応としては「配列を使う」とかになるんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: 別々の変数に格納する事は可能ですが、既に解決済みの様ですね。

Answer (score 1):

いくつか回答いただき、解決したのでまとめます。

```
ans=`awk -F'[ ;]' '$1=="bbbb"{print $2}' test.txt`
```

もしくは

```
ans=`grep -o `bbbb[^;]*` test.txt`
ans=`echo "$ans"|sed -e 's/^bbbb //'`
```

によって変数ansに、「bbbb 」と「;」の間だけを改行込みで抜け出しませました。

次に、

```
IFS='
'
for i in $ans; do
    echo $i
done
```

echoのところに関数を記述する等で、別の変数として扱えました。
回答してくださった皆様ありがとうございました。